# Accessing xlsx sheets using c++/cli

Tags: c#-4.0, c++-cli, excel-2007

I want to imeplement something as shown below in my c++ application c++/cli application. I am using visual studio 2010.

```
static void ReadExcelFileDOM(string fileName)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        string text;
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                text = c.CellValue.Text;
                Console.Write(text + " ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I proceeded as below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define S DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet::Sheets
#define Sheetdata DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet::SheetData
#define Wsheet DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet::WorkbookPart::WorksheetPart
#define E DocumentFormat::OpenXml::OpenXmlElement
#define As DocumentFormat::OpenXml::OpenXmlAttributes
#define A DocumentFormat::OpenXml::OpenXmlAttribute
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Linq;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace DocumentFormat::OpenXml;
using namespace DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging;
using namespace DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::SpreadsheetDocument^ mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument::Open("sample.xlsx", false);
    WorkbookPart^ wp = mySpreadsheet->WorkbookPart;//
    IEnumerable<Sheet>^ sheets = wp->GetFirstChild<Sheet>().Elements<Sheet>();

    return 0;
}
```

The build fails with following errors:

```
1>clitest.cpp(33): error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet::Sheet', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type
1>clitest.cpp(33): error C2039: 'GetFirstChild' : is not a member of 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::WorkbookPart'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\open xml sdk\v2.0\lib\documentformat.openxml.dll : see declaration of 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::WorkbookPart'
1>clitest.cpp(33): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Please if someone could help me on this. I am heldup on this issue.

Regards
**strong text**

Comment: You are going to have to use the hat^ correctly, it is `IEnumerable<Sheet^>` since Sheet is a reference type.  Just like the error message says.  I would recommend that you use .NET's ability to mix assemblies written in different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic types need to be of a class reference type.

```
IEnumerable<Sheet^>
```

Comment: When I tried IEnumerable<Sheet^> sheets = wp->GetFirstChild<Sheet>().Elements<Sheet>(); I tried this also.

Comment: 1>clitest.cpp(33): error C3149: 'System::Collections::Generic::IEnumerable<T>' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Spreadsheet::Sheet ^
1>          ]
1>clitest.cpp(33): error C2039: 'GetFirstChild' : is not a member of 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::WorkbookPart'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\open xml sdk\v2.0\lib\documentformat.openxml.dll : see declaration of 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::WorkbookPart'
1>clitest.cpp(33): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>

Comment: It's not just there... any ref class (.Net class) needs to be declared with a hat (^) ... and every generic class need to take a ref class with a hat.

Comment: Thanks I have moved ahead now.